# Cancel TimerTask that has persisted across redeploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, timertask

I have a JavaEE application deployed to Weblogic 10.3. In my application, I created a `Timer` and `TimerTask` that started at the beginning of the application loading up by doing the following:

```
TimerTask t = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform task
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t, 0, 15000);
```

The problem is, after redeploying the application, the previous timer tasks are still executing. So after 5 deployments, there are 5 timers executing. I don't have the ability to restart the Weblogic server, and I've searched around for a solution but to no avail. Is there any way to stop these  tasks?

I no longer need to use the `TimerTask`, I would just like to stop the ones that are still currently executing.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Using `Timer` in Java EE is in first place already wrong at its own. Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4691132

Comment: Based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983334/how-to-make-ejb-timer-persistent-to-false i would use '@Schedule' which has the persistent property

Comment: This isn't an XY problem. I no longer need to use the TimerTask. My question is how can I stop the tasks currently running, not how can I keep them from persisting. I will edit to clarify this.

Comment: I dont know where weblogic stores its times, but you can find out from weblogic documentation. In wildfly i normally have a folder in the deployment content of the application named ejb-timer-services, where i can manually delete the times.

Comment: You can't. Those threads are not managed by the server due to the severe design mistake of using `Timer` in Java EE as pointed out in that duplicate. Only solution is to restart the server.

Comment: @BalusC, Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882) points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691650/2446208), it is not possible to cancel the `TimerTask`s. The threads are not managed by the server, so the only solution is to restart the server.